# Create pandas DataFrame column from list of indices

Tags: python, pandas

If have a DataFrame and I have a list of row and column indices. I want to create a column out of the DataFrame values, to which the index lists point to.

```
df=pd.DataFrame([[0,1,0],[3,0,0],[4,0,1]])
row_ind=[0,1,2]
col_ind=[1,0,0]
```

So in this case I want to get a new DataFrame which holds the values 1,3,4. I could do this by looping over `zip(row_ind, col_ind)` and then access in every iteration a single DataFrame cell and add it to my new data.

Is there a better alternative, a one-liner? Something like `df.iloc[row_ind,col_ind]` (this returns the whole Dataframe, but I only want the single values in a new DataFrame).

Comment: Does the output need to be a DataFrame or is an array more appropriate? If a DataFrame what would the indices be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use pandas' [lookup](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html) :

```
df.lookup(row_ind,col_ind)
array([1, 3, 4], dtype=int64)
```

you can pass it back as a one column dataframe ... using `pd.DataFrame()`

Comment: This is cool. In the case that you have a list of intexes like `inds = [(r1, c1), (r2, c2), ...]`, you can use `df.lookup(*zip(*inds))`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `numpy`'s fancy indexing:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1, 0], [3, 0, 0], [4, 0, 1]])
row_ind = [0, 1, 2]
col_ind = [1, 0, 0]

series = pd.Series(df.to_numpy()[row_ind, col_ind])
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do it is use `df.values` like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1, 0], [3, 0, 0], [4, 0, 1]])
row_ind = [0, 1, 2]
col_ind = [1, 0, 0]

result = [df.values[row_ind[i], col_ind[i]] for i in range(len(row_ind))]

print(result)
```

returns

```
[1, 3, 4]
```

If you really want it in another dataframe, just add

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(result)
```